# Open all excel files in a folder and record values

Tags: python

I am looking for either a resource to learn this skill, or an example code to make it work.
I need to perform these operations to hundreds of excel files in the same folder:
Open excel file,
read file name and 3 values from certain cells (I'll call them FName, X, and Y),
write these values on the same new line in a text file, in this format:
FName; X; Y; Z;

And then repeat, until I have a text file with all of these values.

I have the data collection part working great.  My issue is that I don't know how to record the file name if it is not in the sheet already, and I don't know how to loop through all the files in a folder.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

##### Gather values #####
x = sheet['F3'].value
y = sheet['C13'].value
if sheet['A17'].value == 'X':
    z = 'Pass'
else:
    z = 'Fail'

##### Append .txt file #####
f = open('example.txt',"a+") # (a)ppend, (w)rite, (r)ead, + is create
f.write(str(x) + ";")
f.write(str(y) + ";")
f.write(z + ";" + "\n")
f.close()
```

Can some one please point me in the right direction to figure out how to do this operation to all the excel files in a folder?

Comment: You are looking for `os.walk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather all the files in a folder use the python module glob. For this example We'll say your files are on your desktop.

```py
import glob
import os # Imported os

f = open('example.txt',"a+") # (a)ppend, (w)rite, (r)ead, + is create

for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\*.xlsx'):  # Change this to your directory
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(rf'{file}')
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    filename = os.path.split(file)[1] # This is the name of the file
    wo_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] # This is the name without .xlsx

    ##### Gather values #####
    x = sheet['F3'].value
    y = sheet['C13'].value
    if sheet['A17'].value == 'X':
        z = 'Pass'
    else:
        z = 'Fail'

    f.write(str(x) + ";")
    f.write(str(y) + ";")
    f.write(z + ";" + "\n")

    wb.close()

f.close()
```

Comment: That was much simpler than I expected.  When trying to run that, python has an issue with this line:  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(rf'{file}').  It says that is invalid syntax.  What does "rf" do?

Comment: ```rf'string'``` just means raw and format. So it makes it a raw string, and formats the file in between the curly brackets. What version of python are you running? It does work on my pc running python v3.7.4

Comment: That makes sense. I normally use python 2, but I also tried this in 3 and got the same error.

Comment: try changing it to ```load_workbook(r'%s' % file)```. I am not too familiar with python 2 but this should work.

Comment: How about just: `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)`

Comment: Both of those worked as far as getting rid of that error, but now it tells me that 'workbook' object has no attribute 'close'.

Comment: You must be running an older version of openpyxl. If you run ```openpyxl.__version__``` it will tell you which version you are on. ```close``` exists on mine running version 2.6.2.

Comment: Yes i see you are running an earlier version as ```get_sheet_by_name``` has been deprecated and would give you a message if you were on the new version. ```pip install --upgrade openpyxl```. If this solves your problems please mark the checkbox to mark the question solved.

Comment: I just ran that, but it didn't change my version, I am still on openpyxl 2.1.4

Comment: Did some searching and you can omit the close statement. It is handled automatically in this particular case.

Comment: Turns out, I had to restart python to make the change (should have known that!)  It works now.  The only part left is getting the name of the file into that string as well.  Is there a quick way of doing that?  Thank you for all your support by the way.

Comment: I appreciate your help!